# Why can a control draw outside its bounding box?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, drawing

Here's an example image of what I mean: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUFwN.png)

The gray rectangle is the bounding box of a control that draws the blue lines and dots in it's `OnRender(...)` method. The red ovals mark places where it happens.

- Why is that possible?
- How can it be avoided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750441(v=vs.100).aspx has detailed information about the architectural design of WPF to answer why it is possible.

To avoid it you want to use the [clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip%28VS.95%29.aspx) property of your element.

```
 <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Height="100" Width="200" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black">
   <Rectangle.Clip>
     <EllipseGeometry Center="200,100" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" />
   </Rectangle.Clip>
 </Rectangle>
```

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189065%28v=VS.95%29.aspx for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed it has to do with something like a display tree, but couldn't find any documentation about it. For the how it can be avoided, I was searching for something easier than doing manual clipping - and I just found the solution I was hoping for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588678.aspx

Comment: Side note: the link above refers to the latest version of .Net framework (4.5 as of now) where the article "WPF architecture" is not available. To see it you will need to switch to version 4.0.

Comment: what about when I'm drawing a text, how to clip it? `drawingContext.DrawText(....)`, sometimes it will draw the text outside the bounds. I could check for that and not draw the text, however I want to draw and clip, so only part of the text is shown

Comment: never mind... I needed to use `ClipToBounds` on the parent control, that solved the problem

Answer (score 18):

Here's the perfect answer to my second question, at least when using a rectangular shaped control:

```
<object ClipToBounds="True" />
```

More details on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588678.aspx).